# Potential stale tip detected while shutting down Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core

I tried to shut down Bitcoin Core and it took a very long time. So I looked in the log file and found the following messages:

```
2023-12-18T18:36:58Z Shutdown: In progress...
2023-12-18T18:36:58Z net thread exit
2023-12-18T18:49:47Z [net] Flushed 75923 addresses to peers.dat  1272ms
2023-12-18T19:02:52Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 2205 seconds ago)
2023-12-18T19:02:52Z [net] setting try another outbound peer=true
2023-12-18T19:04:48Z [net] Flushed 75923 addresses to peers.dat  1056ms
2023-12-18T19:13:22Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 2835 seconds ago)
2023-12-18T19:13:22Z [net] setting try another outbound peer=true
2023-12-18T19:19:51Z [net] Flushed 75923 addresses to peers.dat  3289ms
```

Before this happened, I was trying to get a lightning node to connect to the bitcoin node and one of the things I tried was to create a symbolic link to the bitcoin data directory because the lightning node could not access the directory directly because the name contains spaces.

Could that have caused this problem? If not, what else might have caused it?

More importantly, how long might this take?  The node has been "shutting down" now for almost an hour.

Comment: Is this the only output you're seeing? Is there CPU usage? Which version of Bitcoin Core is this? It seems wrong that it's trying to create extra outbound connections while shutting down...

Comment: It is version 25.0.0. If I run `top`, I don't see `bitcoin-qt` or `bitcoind` anywhere in the list, so I don't think it there is much CPU usage.

Comment: @PieterWuille And yes, the three messages shown above are the only output I see in `debug.log` and it repeats over and over.